# Alternative drawable resources for my app. Scaling down XHDPI

Tags: android, photoshop

I have made design for android app specially for XHDPI devices. I want to support all screen densities ldpi and highier. Is it okay to scale my XHDPI design down in photoshop , for each density?

Or I need to make my design from scratch for every density to maintain the quality?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling down is absolutely ok. There're many scripts for Photoshop which could do it for you. For instance [Cutandslice](http://www.cutandslice.me)